# Set up G Suit account in Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-workspace

I have a Google Compute engine account, do I need to pay for G suite, since I'm hosting my website with Google?
How do I set up G suit account in my Compute Engine?
Thanks

Martins F

Answer (score 0):

Yes, G suite i a google package of its own.
to get stated, you need an administrator account to access gsuite or you can create one here [sign in to admin console](http://admin.google.com.)